How do I limit bitrate not larger than the source file rate?
I have a batch of videos from mixed sources which I want to reduce in size. Some of them are high resolution and high bitrate videos, but some are low  bitrate clips received through Viber or similar channels. I want to make a batch command line that takes the original file and limits it to 1920x1080 and limits its bit rate to 4096000.
I have reached the following command so far :
 "C:\ffmpeg-full\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "%~fi" -vcodec libx264 -vf "scale='if(gt(iw,ih),min(iw,1920),-1)':'if(gt(iw,ih),-1,min(ih,1920))'" -b:v 4096000 -b:a 256k -y "d:\tmp2%~pnxi"

It reduces the frame size if necessary and forces the video bitrate to 4096000. This works great for large files with higher bitrate, but makes small videos coming from Viber, much larger. Is there a way to limit the bitrate value not to be larger than the source bitrate value? Something like
-b:v min(ibitrate:4096000)

I can't find anything similar in forums or google. the max_rate option doesn't seem to be made for such thing.

Well, since you have a batch script, you could get the bitrate from the metadata and put it into a variable to set the bitrate in your ffmpeg command:
@ECHO on

set input="filename.webm"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('ffmpeg -i %input% 2^>^&1 ^| findstr "bitrate"') do (set bitrate=%%b);
set bitrate=%bitrate:~41,8%  

ffmpeg -i "%~fi" -vcodec libx264 -vf "scale='if(gt(iw,ih),min(iw,1920),-1)':'if(gt(iw,ih),-1,min(ih,1920))'" -b:v %bitrate% -b:a 256k -y "d:\tmp2%~pnxi"

You may have to try different trimming of the bitrate string, depending on the metadata output. You can check it with Ffprobe. You probably know.

Another way
Here is a more convenient way to do it by using ffprobe to directly get the bitrate value, like @nd34567s32e noted. Unfortunately it uses a temporary file to store the value. Couldn't make it run in a loop.
@ECHO off
set input=input.mp4

:: Save the ffprobe output into a temp file
ffprobe -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries format=bit_rate -v quiet -of csv="p=0" %input% > temp_output.txt

:: Read the temp file value and store it into a variable
for /f "delims=" %%A in (temp_output.txt) do set "bitrate=%%A"

:: Deleting temp file
del temp_output.txt

:: Encoding
ffmpeg -i "%~fi" -vcodec libx264 -vf "scale='if(gt(iw,ih),min(iw,1920),-1)':'if(gt(iw,ih),-1,min(ih,1920))'" -b:v %bitrate% -b:a 256k -y "d:\tmp2%~pnxi"


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 INPUT.MP4 will output only the bitrate value.
Worked on MP4 and AVI for me. succeeded on a proper MOV, failed on an MOV that had no moov atom.

@nd34567s32e True. But I would rather use ffprobe -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries format=bit_rate -v quiet -of csv="p=0" INPUT.webm. This way it works for mp4 and webm as well
